# FFmpeg: afade plugin, how to specify time 1:55 if colon separates filter parameters? Escape

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, filter

I want to make a fade out in a video, using the [afade](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade) audio filter.

Here's my command:

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO06.mp4 -c:v copy -af afade=t=out:curve=hsin:st=00:0:30:duration=00:00:10 VIDEO06-faded.mp4
```

But appearantly that's wrong, because `':'` separates the filter arguments.

How can I specify the time in H:M:S format (here's [ffmpeg's duration syntax](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax)) within the params? Or how can I escape the colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the time argument in single quotes and escape the colons within.

So,

```
afade=t=out:curve=hsin:st='00\:0\:30':d='00\:00\:10'
```

Comment: For me it needed two backslashes: `afade=t=out:curve=hsin:st='00\\:0\\:30':d='00\\:00\\:10'`, or, if you want to do it without quotes: `afade=t=out:curve=hsin:st=00\\\\:0\\\\:30:d=00\\\\:00\\\\:10`.